# Is this ok if library has some side effects?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, architecture, software-distribution

I'm developing some Kotlin libraries and I have the following conceptual issues:

1. The first library is based on spring's classpath scanner and is intended for use as a spring extension, so it pulls spring-core as a dependency. Is this ok? How would the potential user of my library handle different spring versions?
2. The second library is based on first and it is intended for use in p2p networks. It synchronizes with other peers and provides a shared state that can be easily retrieved by library user using special pre-defined spring service. Is this ok for a library to have side effect like this? Maybe there are some patterns for implementing/distributing such libraries?

If this is not ok, can you please guide me how to do this right.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having side-effects isn't alone a problem, especially if the entire purpose of the library is to, at some point, carry out side effects. Whatever side effects you do have however should be focused to one part in your program. The rest of the program can operate using pure functions, and just pass processed data to some side-effect-causing function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit general question, and having concrete examples would help understand if that's "okay" or "not okay" to do it.

But generally speaking:

1. It's fine if your library depends on other libraries of specific versions. Most of the libraries do. The question is how heavy and obtrusive this library you depend on is. And unfortunately for you, Spring libraries are known to be both. In case of the end-user of your library, in case of conflicts he'll simply have to choose whether he wants to update his Spring version for your library or not
2. Having some distributed state is not necessarily a side effect. EhCache is a distributed cache library, for example. The basic pattern is to be as SOLID as possible. When I developed [caching for Vert.x WebClient library](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/pull/892), I made it rely on interfaces instead of solid implementation, so if someone decides he doesn't want to use your library (Spring component, for example), he could provide an alternative solution.

Again, those are basic guidelines, without seeing your code. If you intend to open source it, feel free to share specific bits to get more concrete insights from StackOverflow community.